# Testing in Angular with service dependency

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm trying to write my first Angular 6 test. I have a component which returns a list of Companies from a service.

It looks like this:

Template

```
 <div *ngFor="let company of this.companies">
  <h4 id="company-{{company.id}}>{{company.name}}</h4>
 </div>
```

Component.ts

```
import { ApiService } from '../service/api.service';

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.companies = this.apiService.getCompanies();
}
```

Service

```
import { COMPANYLIST } from '../companyList';

companyList = COMPANYLIST;

public getCompanies(): Company[] {
  return this.companyList;
}
```

I would like to test that I can see the list of Companies in the component. In my spec.ts I have tried to add a mocked apiService as per https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-a-dependency with no luck.

I'm guessing the test should look something like this, but I am having issues actually injecting the mocked service into this test.

```
  it("should show the list of Companies", () => {
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector("company-" + this.company.id).textContent).toContain("Mock Company");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The strategy is to inject a place holder object for your service. In the test get a reference to that place holder object and then add fake functionality to it that will be called when testing the component.

Example (*I omitted code that does not illustrate the point I am trying to make*)

```
import { ApiService } from '../service/api.service';

describe('CompaniesComponent Tests', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [CompaniesComponent],
            providers: [
                { provide: ApiService, useValue: {} }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
        TestBed.compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CompaniesComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    });


    it("should show the list of Companies", () => {
      // get service and fake a returned company list 
      const apiService = TestBed.get(ApiService) as ApiService;
      apiService.getCompanies = () => ['Mock Company'];

      // you probably need to call ngOnInit on your component so it retrieves the companies from the api service
      comp.ngOnInit();
      const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      expect(compiled.querySelector("company-" + this.company.id).textContent).toContain("Mock Company");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock your service :

```
export class MockCompanyService {

  getCompanies: Spy;

  constructor(config) {
    this.getCompanies = jasmine.createSpy('getCompanies').and.callFake(() => config.companies);
   }
}
```

In your test, you will give `companies` to you mock so when your function is called, you will have your companies displayed.:

```
describe('CompanyComponent', () => {
  let component: CompanyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CompanyComponent>;
  let element;

  const mockCompanies = [
     ...
  ]; 

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    return TestBed
      .configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
          CompanyComponent
        ],
        imports: [],
        providers: [
          {
            provide: ComponentFixtureAutoDetect,
            useValue: true
          }
        ]
      })
      .overrideComponent(CompanyComponent, {
        set: {
          providers: [
            {provide: CompanyService, useValue: new MockCompanyService(mockCompanies)}
          ]
        }
      })
      .compileComponents()
      .then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CompanyComponent);
        component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
        element = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      });
  }));


  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('...', () => {

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your example the unit test should be pretty simple to implement.

It should be something like that:

```
describe("path", () => {

   let component: Component; 
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component>
   let service: Service;

   beforeEach(() => {
     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [Component],
      providers: [Service]
    });

    fixture = TestBet.CreateComponent(Component)
    service = TestBed.get(Service)
   });

   afterEach(() => {
     fixture.destroy();
   });

   it("Component_Method_WhatDoYouExpect", () => {
      let testCompanies = [{c1}....];

      let spy = spyOn(service, "getCompanies").and.returnValue(testCompanies);

      component.ngOnInit();

      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(component.companies).toEqual(testCompanies);
   });
});
```

You have to create a test file for the component and one for the service. 
In service test you should do almost the same like above, but there you have to initialize the company list, to call the method and to verify if the result is right.

service.companyList = [c1, c2...]

let res = service.GetCompanies();

expect(res).toEqual(service.companyList);

[Here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/angular-test-bed/) you can find more information about TestBed and Unit tests.

Comment: I forgot asign the instance of the Component from fixture to component. So, under fixture= TestBed.CreateComponent(component); , add component = fixture.componentInstance;